# Mapping a point to the derivative of a function at that point.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be $C^1$, so that all of its first partial derivatives exist and are continuous. Under what conditions is the map $x\mapsto df_x$ smooth?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'smooth'? The derivative is a linear map whose matrix entries are the partial derivatives, so the function is continuous.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The map $x\mapsto df_x$ is a map from $R^n$ to $R^{m\times n}$. This map is obviously continuous but it makes sense to talk about the derivative of this map. I'm asking under what conditions is this map differentiable?

Comment: If $f$ has continuous second partial derivatives then $df_x$ is differentiable.